Podem ou Poderem [Tradução de A Morte de Ivan Ilitch]
Minha dúvida vem do seguinte trecho:

Era filho de um funcionário, que fizera em São Petersburgo, em diferentes
ministérios e departamentos, aquele tipo de carreira que leva as pessoas a uma situação
da qual elas, por mais evidente que seja a sua incapacidade para qualquer função de efetiva importância, não podem ser expulsas, em virtude dos muitos anos de serviço e dos postos avançados;

Me parece mais apropriado não poderem, porém meu nível de conhecimento sobre minha própria língua é altamente questionável.

"da qual elas [...] não podem ser expulsas" é uma declaração feita em um tempo de verbo simples para expressar um estado. Não há motivo para usar o infinitivo pessoal.

Na verdade, uso de "podem", no presente do indicativo, está correto. Para entender melhor, basta mudar a ordem da frase:

"aquele tipo de carreira que leva as pessoas a uma situação da qual elas não podem ser expulsas,em virtude dos muitos anos de serviço e dos postos avançados, por mais evidente que seja a sua incapacidade para qualquer função de efetiva importância."

